# ModuleNotFoundError: Even with __init__.py file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 python file :

test.py
modules(folder) and in modules there 3 to files : module1.py module2.py  **init**.py
test.py

```
./test.py
./modules
./modules/module1.py
./modules/module2.py
./modules/__init__.py
```

module1.py:

```
from module2 import temp

def print_temp():
    print(temp)
    
if __name__=='__main__':
    print_temp()
```

module2.py

```
temp =1
```

test.py

```
from modules.module1 import print_temp
print_temp()
```

When I run `python test.py` I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'`

How can I fix that please?

Comment: Yes, because "modules" is not in the search list.  Have you tried a relative import, `from .module2 import temp`?  (Note the dot before module2)

Comment: It's looking for a top-level import called `module2`. Either try to import `modules.module2` or try a relative import, `from .module2 import temp`.

Comment: @TimRoberts `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: @vtable that shouldn't happen if the module is being imported, only it is being run directly. If you want to be able to run it directly use a full absolute import: `from modules.module2 import temp`

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module in Python, it searches the `PYTHONPATH` for a module / package with that name. But it doesn't search inside directories so you have to specify.

If you want to be able to run `modules.module1` directly (as well as import it) then you must use the full path:

```py
from modules.module2 import temp
```

But if you just want to be able to import the module and not run it directly it is better to use a relative import as it will still work even if the name of the package is changed:

```py
from .module2 import temp
```

Comment: So why did I got `attempted relative import with no known parent package` ? Thanks!

Comment: @vtable That's what happens when you directly run a module containing a relative import, which is why you need to do an absolute import if you want to be able to run it directly. Relative imports only work when it is being imported